# How does C# chart series connects the missing dots on the screen?

Tags: c#, charts

I have a C# Windows Forms application in which there is a screen designed to show a `Graph` using the `DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` class where the X axis are composed of `DateTime` and the Y Axis are composed of integers (the goal is to represent the memory usage in MB over time of some other processes). So, I want to display this in a format of a [Continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function). But when I set the `DataVisualization.Charting.Series` object type to `SeriesChartType.Line` the Form plots the graph in a very strange way, see image below:

[image]

and when I set the object series type to `SeriesChartType.Point` the displayed graph is:

[image]

**Notice that** there are a lot of points that are in blank and that's ok because there aren't any registry of memory usage between those time intervals. The only problem I'm complaining here is that in the `Line` mode the graph is being plotted in this strange way. The code for the generation of these graphs is:

```
private void CarregaSerieMemoria()
    {
        // this InvokeRequired is because it is called in a separeted Thread, the graph creation happens in the Else block
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            VoidVoidDelegate d = new VoidVoidDelegate(CarregaSerieMemoria);
            this.Invoke(d);
        }
        else
        {
            try {
                // Data table containing the Memory Usage history
                foreach (DataRow row in Dados.dsComponentes.Tables["MemoryHistory"].Rows)
                {
                    string proc = row["NomeProcesso"].ToString();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proc))
                    {
                        string dataStr = row["TimeStamp"].ToString();
                        string memoriaStr = row["Memoria"].ToString();
                        DateTime data;
                        int memoria;
                        try
                        {
                            data = DateTime.ParseExact(dataStr, "yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            memoria = int.Parse(memoriaStr) / 1000;
                        }
                        catch (FormatException)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (TemSerieProc(proc))
                        { // if there is already a Series object with proc name
                            Series s = this.chartMemory.Series.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(proc)).FirstOrDefault();
                            s.Points.AddXY(data, memoria);
                        }
                        else
                        {   // else creates a new Series object and add this current point (data,memoria)
                            Series s = DefineNovaSerie(proc);
                            s.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
                            s.Points.AddXY(data, memoria);
                            this.chartMemory.Series.Add(s);
                        }
                    }
                }

                chartMemory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
                chartMemory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 30;
                chartMemory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
                chartMemory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 1;
                chartMemory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = graphDateBegin.ToOADate();
                chartMemory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = graphDateEnd.AddHours(24).ToOADate();

                chartMemory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
                chartMemory.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
                chartMemory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
                chartMemory.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;

                chartMemory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Horário";
                chartMemory.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Memória (MegaBytes)";

                chartMemory.MouseWheel += chartMemory_MouseWheel;
                chartMemory.MouseClick += chartMemory_MouseClick;
                chartMemory.Visible = true;
                labelLoad.Visible = false;
                btnReload.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private Series DefineNovaSerie(string proc)
    {

        Series temp = new Series(proc);

        temp.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        //temp.MarkerSize = 10;
        temp.Color = GetNextColor(nextColorInt++);

        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Try an OrderBy on your Table.

Comment: Have you done anything (in code not shown) to try to impose a particular *order* to the data?

Comment: It looks like the points are not ordered on the x-Axis.

Comment: There are many chart types. Often points are ordered in the order you add them; sometimes they follow the x-values. Point and line do the latter so you can create any kind of graphs with them. If the x-avlues matter order by them, if they don't you can set series.XValuesAreIndexed = true.

Comment: thanks, the ordering was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You populating chart from not ordered data. Your x axis is date so your data should be ordered by date when adding point to chart.
Here is an example (not tested) how you might fix the issue by sorting your data from datatable on `TimeStamp` field.

```
var dataTable = Dados.dsComponentes.Tables["MemoryHistory"];
var orderedDataView = new DataView(dataTable);
orderedDataView.Sort = "TimeStamp";
foreach (DataRow row in orderedDataView.ToTable().Rows)
{
    //rest of code
}
```